# 1976 Beetle 1600 curved windscreen

Tags: vw

I'm looking for and any information on this particular model. Specifically wiring informtion.
Would also like to know how many were manufactured?

Answer (score 2):

Wiring Diagram [here](http://www.thesamba.com/vw/archives/info/wiring/76-79113wiring.jpg) with [key](http://www.thesamba.com/vw/archives/info/wiring/76-79113wiring-key.jpg).

More at [The Samba](http://www.thesamba.com/vw/archives/info/wiringt1.php).

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to find what you're looking for [here](http://volkswagenownersclub.com/vw/forumdisplay.php/146-Aircooled-Classic-Beetle-Technical-Forum).  This [source](http://www.thesamba.com/vw/archives/info/beetle_productionfigures.php) indicates total 1976 production was 383,277.